# ¿Se puede pasar contenido de un archivo .txt a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo varios archivos .txt igual a este contenido

Contenido:

```
0 69 164
0 71 117
0 73 84
0 79 80
0 82 83
0 82 115
0 83 154
0 84 48
1 69 104
1 71 100
1 73 83
1 79 82
1 82 121
1 83 117
1 84 46
2 69 204
2 71 94
2 73 85
2 79 102
2 82 88
2 82 147
2 83 87
2 84 42
```

Lo quiero pasar a JSON, con ada columna con diferentes campos, siguiendo el formato:

```
'[{"user":"0","tecla":"69","time":"164"}, ... ]'
```

¿Se puede?

Comment: Qué formato tiene que tener el json?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo '{"user":"0","tecla":"69","time":"164"}'; ect

Comment: Recién veo el comentario, corrijo mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### usando solo arreglos de arreglos:

si la variable texto tiene ese txt se puede hacer esto:

```
var arreglo = texto.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(linea){
    return linea.split(' ');
};
var arregloJson = JSON.stringify(arreglo);
```

De ese modo arreglo es igual a:

```
[[0, 69, 164], [0, 71, 117], etc... ]
```

y arregloJson es igual al string *JSONeado*:

```
"[[0, 69, 164], [0, 71, 117], etc... ]"
```

### usando un objeto según el segundo comentario

```
var arreglo = texto.split(/\r?\n/).map(function(linea){
    var numeros = linea.split(' ');
    return {user: numeros[0], tecla: numeros[1], time: numeros[2]};
};
var arregloJson = JSON.stringify(arreglo);
```

### notas:

1. El `split(/\r?\n/)` usa una expresión regular que separa tanto líneas de Linux (separadas por `\n`) como líneas de Windows (separadas por `\r\n`)
2. El código propuesto puede ser usado también del lado del cliente en todos los navegadores actuales.

Answer (score 2):

NodeJS incorpora un [`módulo`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) para leer líneas:

```
const obj = {};
const fs = require('fs');
const lr = require('readline');

console.log(obj.length);
var lineReader = lr.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('dummy.txt')
});

lineReader.on('line', function (line) {
    let [ user, tecla, time ] = line.split(' ');
    obj[Object.keys(obj).length || 0] = { user, tecla, time };
});

lineReader.on('close', ()=>{
    fs.writeFile("dummy.txt", JSON.stringify(obj), function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("Convertido a JSON");
    });

});
```

Comment: Debería ser la respuesta aceptada, pero marcaría que sólo se está imprimiendo el objeto, en vez de devolverlo como JSON.

Comment: He editado con tu recomendación! =)

Answer (score 1):

Esta sería una manera, habiendo obtenido previamente el contenido del .txt y guardandolo en un string:

```js
var str = "0 69 164\n0 71 117\n0 73 84\n0 79 80\n0 82 83";
var lines = str.split("\n");
var data_json = [];
var tmp;

for(var index in lines){
 tmp = lines[index].trim().split(" ");
 data_json.push({
  user : tmp[0],
  tecla : tmp[1],
  time : tmp[2]
 });
}
console.log(data_json);
```

Answer (score 1):

yo cree esta funcion para un archivo csv, para un archivo de texto sera igual...

```
function processFiles(files) {
    var file = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var output = document.getElementById("fileOutput");
        var texto = e.target.result;
        csvJSON(texto);
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}

function csvJSON(csv) {
    var lines = csv.split("\n");
    var result = [];
    var headers;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        headers = lines[i].split("\n");
    }
    var cont = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {

        var obj = {};
        var currentline = lines[i].split("\n");
        for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
            obj[cont] = currentline[j];
        }
        cont++;
        result.push(obj);
    }

    return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
```